# Trying to send a picture to telegram via php

Tags: javascript, php, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to send a picture to telegram via php, but it does not send...

(The image in the base64 file type)

**JS:**

```
var imagg;
function convertCanvasToImage(canvas) { // canvas = data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0....
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  imagg = image.src;
  return image;
 }        

setTimeout(function() {
$.post("telegram.php", {uu: imagg}, function(data) {
                // returned from php
             });
}, 5000);
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$uu = $_GET['uu'];

$apiToken = "TOKEN.....";

$data = [
    'chat_id' => '@CHAT_ID...',
    'photo' => $uu,
    'caption' => 'Markdown'

];

$response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$apiToken/sendPhoto?" . http_build_query($data) );
?>
```

Comment: "it does not send" is not a valid error message.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include the error message @pro-fire

Comment: You send your Ajax request as a POST but then PHP tries to read from the GET variables. Clearly these two things are not the same.  Try `$uu = $_POST['uu'];` instead

Answer (score -1):

Change your php code to this and it should work

```php
<?php
$uu = $_GET['uu'];//or $_POST['uu'];

$photoData = explode(',', $uu)[1];
$photoDataDecoded = base64_decode($photoData);

$apiToken = "TOKEN.....";

$data = [
    'chat_id' => '@CHAT_ID...',
    'photo' => new \CURLStringFile($photoDataDecoded, 'file.png'),
    'caption' => 'Markdown'
];

$response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$apiToken/sendPhoto?" . http_build_query($data) );
?>
```